# How To Pass Data Between Shopify "THEME-APP-EXTENSION" And The Backend Of The App?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to figure out how to pass data between the theme-app-extension and the backend of the application that the theme-app-extension is connected to. The theme-app-extension is all liquid, css, and javascript so I wasn't sure if there was a built in way to pass data between the two. For example is there a suggested method to pull data into the theme-app-extension from the database and is there a suggested way to send data to the database from the code running the theme-app-extension? I am fairly new to doing anything with theme-app-extensions as well as building Shopify applications. I have built Shopify applications that was admin facing or just cosmetic, this is my first time building a Shopify application that takes user input and sends it to the database and retrieves that data for the end-user to see.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What David Lazar suggested is the way to go without over engineering and complicating things.
I suggest that you read more about [Shopify app proxy](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/app-proxies).
I used app proxy in my app ([FieldsRaven](https://apps.shopify.com/fieldsraven)) to create and update metafields from the frontend of the store.
Storefront > app proxy > FieldsRaven > Shopify API 
then
Shopify API > FieldsRaven > Storefront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually (always) pass data from the front-end to the back-end using an App Proxy. There really is no other way at this time. The Proxy gives you an XHR call you can use, and you can return Liquid or JSON. Your choice.

Answer (score 3):

I started working on Shopify App (Theme App Extension) a week ago

I run into the same problem, so I did consume API in a javascript file using Fetch
Here is an example of the code:

[image]

I add this into global.js file inside assets

[image]

And then I linked the script files inside my Liquid block

[image]

Also inside global.js, I did manipulate DOM by injecting data consumed from API, here is an example

[image]

**Finally what I did is communicate directly with DOM to inject or retrieve data, then handle it using javascript**

I hope this helps you

Ps:
This is my first experience with Shopify too, and I was quite disappointed (lack of resources, docs, and community)

Comment: Welcome to Shopify! = lack of resources, docs, and community.

Comment: The question was specifically how to communication with an App, assuming that meant Admin access. Your approach is easier since your fetch() call is not authenticated, hence it has no security.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Shopify [metafields API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/metafield) in your backend to add metafields on product, app...

Then in your liquid block you can get the metafield like

```
<script>
    MY_VAR = '{{ app.metafields.mynamespace.myvar }}';
</script>
```

More information on metafields on the [Shopify blog](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/metafields)

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 2 ways to do so:

1. Metafields. Your backend creates metafields on the entity and you use liquid to render the data for your app blocks
2. App proxy and your app API. Set up an app proxy to fix cross origin between Shopify and your app. Use ajax call to retrieve data from your backend

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the app details (I just need the name) from the JS of the theme app extension?

Comment: No, I don't think the app name is passed to a js variable

Comment: Can I get it from liquid?

Comment: no, I don't see the app name is passed as a liquid field. But you can use metafield to do so. Section setting is also ok